# URL escape for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, escaping

I have the following url:

```
http://s7w2p3.scene7.com/is/agm/creativprint/a4?&page=3&wid=354&fmt=jpg,rgb&setAttr.img_page3={source=@Embed%28%27/ugc/8423326.tif%27%29}.
```

I want to set this as the url of background-image of a div via `jQuery('#divID').css` or `document.getElementByID('divID').style.backgroundImage`. It does not work, as I suppose I have to escape some charaters in it. The Javascript global function escape() doesnt do the trick either.

I have set it manually as background-image in my .css file and it works. Any suggestions? I have tried it with other URLs of the format `http://s7w2p3.scene7.com/is/agm/creativprint/a4?&page=3&wid=354&fmt=jpg,rgb`. That works. So the problem must be in the remaining part: `&setAttr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have just forgotten the `url()` around the CSS property:

```
$('#id').css('backgroundImage', 'url("http://s7w2p3.scene7.com/is/agm/creativprint/a4?&page=1&wid=354&fmt=jpg,rgb&setAttr.img_page1={source=@Embed%28%27/ugc/4575272.tif%27%29}")');
```

It works fine for me that way: http://jsfiddle.net/mPyTJ/1/

Comment: Sry for the url not working, the image has been removed in the meantime, here is a working one: http://s7w2p3.scene7.com/is/agm/creativprint/a4?&page=1&wid=354&fmt=jpg,rgb&setAttr.img_page1=%7Bsource=@Embed('/ugc/4575272.tif')%7D 
I definitely have the url() around the property, as it works for other urls as well. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: It works for me (see the fiddle link)... Maybe your code is never called, e.g. due to a syntax error or an exception earlier in your code?

Comment: Thx ThiefMaster and jfreij. I recognized in your fiddle that the ' and () in the url have been replaced by stackoverflow by %27%28 and %29. That works! My original url in the fiddle doesnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/g6P62/5/ 
So what function does stackoverflow use to only replace (encode) the symbols "( ) '"?

Comment: Actually I just pasted your URL in my browser's address bar and then copied it again, in its properly-urlencoded form.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what your problem is. Everything seems to be working just fine. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6P62/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div1').css('backgroundImage','url(http://s7w2p3.scene7.com/is/agm/creativprint/a4?&page=1&wid=354&fmt=jpg,rgb&setAttr.img_page1={source=@Embed%28%27/ugc/4575272.tif%27%29})');
});
```

If you could reproduce your error using jsFiddle that would help a lot.